# Why is there a reputation requirement for flagging?

Tags: discussion, flags, reputation, new-users, privileges

I noticed that you can't flag a question without sufficient reputation (15 rep).

Why is there this restriction?

Letting more people be able to flag, I admit, might clog up the flag review queue with useless flags, but certain filters may be put up into place to block spam flags. At the same time, you can also maximize the number of active users at the moment to identify bad questions quickly.

Comment: So you have suggestion "but certain filters may be put up into place to block spam flags." that is implemented by "require 15 rep to flag"... Consider your wish granted.

Comment: No wonder you are THE REP HUNTER.

Comment: @itachi well, sue me

Answer (score 17):

Users with less than 15 reputation are not likely to know what types of questions are or are not suitable for Stack Overflow, and thus a relatively high percentage of their flags would be noise rather than signal.

Granted, it's not a perfect heuristic, and pretty much anyone can tell that a question about gardening is off-topic, but these blatantly off-topic questions don't tend to hang around very long anyway, even without flags from users with less than 15 reputation, since we have plenty of users with sufficient reputation around to raise such flags.

I am sympathetic to the idea of allowing *anyone*—including anonymous users— to raise custom flags for moderator attention (i.e., flags where you have to type out an explanation in a textbox giving your reason, and flags that are handled only by diamond moderators, in contrast to flags that end up in the review queues), but even that entails serious concerns about the signal-to-noise ratio.

Do you have a specific reason why you think that the reputation requirement for flagging should be lifted? It's important to understand that, on Stack Overflow, a reputation limit of 15 is considered to be an *extremely* low bar. That's fewer than 2 upvotes, which can be accomplished with a single great post or two mediocre posts. It would represent maybe an hour or two worth of engagement with the site. If you haven't yet or aren't willing to put in that level of engagement, why would you be interested in flagging? And why would we expect to be able to trust your flags?

Comment: It wasn't an editing error, @Martijn; I actually wrote it that way. But your edit turns out to be just as clear, if not more so than the original, so I'm going to go with it. :-)

Comment: You can just hit rollback, there is a convenient link under your post for that. Be warned that multiple rollbacks does raise a mod flag in which case your post will be locked and if your actions or the editor actions are off-limits suspensions might be handed out. #modfight

Comment: I just keeping hitting it until it goes away, right, @rene?

Comment: And by “it”, Cody of course referred to myself! ;-)